# urlib.request.retrieve to a user specified file with a variable as a parameter

Tags: python, pycharm

as part of my assingment i'm supposed to create this automatic python downloader. It works by retrieveing links from a text file called "urls.txt". Part of the assingment is to get us to make it download said links into a specified destination, and to also print that it's being downloaded to the user specified file. So far i've tried to work on the user speciied location  part, but my teachers can't help me too much so here i am. The script comes with an error function that displays if the "try" exception isn't met. Anyways heres the code.

```
import os.path
import urllib.request


linksFile = input("Please specify the path to the text file:")
f = open(linksFile + '.txt', 'r')
links = f.readlines()
for link in links:


    # Get one line of text (e.g. http://server/files/grades.doc),
    # then get the filename from the end of the URL
    link = link.strip()
    print(link)
    filename = link.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    print(filename)

    # Does this file exist in this folder? If not, download it
    if not (os.path.isfile(filename)):
        print('Downloading: ' + filename)

        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(filename, '/Users/mattt/Documents/python.script.downloads')
            print('Downloading: ' + filename)
            print("File size was", os.path.getsize(filename))
        except Exception as inst:
            print(inst)
            print('  Encountered unknown error. Continuing.')

    # File exists; don't download
    else:
        print("This file exists already.")

# End of program
print("Finished downloading.")
```

**The issue is that it throws out this error message for some reason**

```
Please specify the path to the text file:C:/Users/mattt/documents/urls

http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/g2/Mugs/20050213/mugs_050213_014.jpg
mugs_050213_014.jpg
Downloading: mugs_050213_014.jpg
unknown url type: 'mugs_050213_014.jpg'
Encountered unknown error. Continuing.

http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/g2/Mugs/20050213/mugs_050213_008b.jpg
mugs_050213_008b.jpg
Downloading: mugs_050213_008b.jpg
unknown url type: 'mugs_050213_008b.jpg'
Encountered unknown error. Continuing.

http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/g2/Mugs/20050213/mugs_050213_006.jpg
mugs_050213_006.jpg
Downloading: mugs_050213_006.jpg
unknown url type: 'mugs_050213_006.jpg'
Encountered unknown error. Continuing.

Finished downloading.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only passing the file name, you want to pass the full URL to the image when downloading it :

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, '/Users/mattt/Documents/python.script.downloads')
```

Comment: thanks for the contribution, i tried that and it threw this out                                     
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mattt/PycharmProjects/sandbox/Script.py", line 6, in <module>
    f = open(linksFile + '.txt', 'r')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '  C:/Users/mattt/Documents/urls.txt'

Comment: Does that .txt file not contain the valid remote URL's? Perhaps add the content of the file to your original post